# Securely erase hard drives and SSDs from WinPE

Tags: security, hardware, wiping

Are there any tools for securely deleting all data that:

- Will run from Windows PE (because I want to use it as part of an MDT deployment task sequence)
- Work on both hard drives and SSDs (SSDs aren't usually fully erased by writing over the whole visible space - their secure erase function needs to be called)
- Preferably free, or at least cheap

What I've looked at so far:

- [HDDErase/Secure Erase](http://cmrr.ucsd.edu/people/Hughes/secure-erase.html) - only works from DOS, and even then requires you to turn off AHCI in the bios first.
- [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/secure-erase/) - The only other tool I've found that can securely erase SSDs.  Would be perfect if it was WinPE instead of linux.
- [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) - Doesn't securely erase SSDs, requires it's own boot CD.  Their commercial product, Blancco says it does, but they don't even list pricing information in their site so I get to deal with sales people now :)
- [sdelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx) - Looks promising, but I can't find any reliable source to say it works well to properly clear SSDs.
- various manufacturer specific tools - will only work on their particular brand.  Some are windows based, some DOS.

Answer (score 2):

When my company was looking into this we tried out a number of solutions such as the ones you listed and the main issue was SSD erasure. Most of them say they erase SSDs but all they do is enable Secure Erase and say that it was erased. That's all fine and dandy except there are tests that show Secure Erase does not work 100% of the time for SSDs.(see Grupp L., Spada F., Swanson S., Wei M., “Reliably Erasing Data From Flash-based Solid State Drives,” 2010)

To my directors displeasure the only solution that did not fully rely on Secure Erase was Blancco's. Director was mad cause it was also the most expensive solution. We didn't really care because it works and we don't deal with the cost side of things. There's my anecdote.

Comment: That research is from 2010. Also Blanco has limitations with SSD's (https://support.blancco.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=66135). Bottom line is that SSD's (and also SMR drives) keep significant amount of blocks outside user accessible LBA which are out of reach for any overwrite tool.

IOW if you can not rely on secure erase, enhanced secure erase, crypto erase, only alternative is physical destruction IMO.